# AngularFire Check if item of same title exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I have Firebase entries in `/items` with the properties `title` and `points`. I am trying to check to see if an item of the same `title` exists before entering a new one.

This is what I have but it does not happen:

```
app.controller('ItemController', function($scope, FURL, $firebase, $location, toaster) {

  var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
  var fbItems = $firebase(ref.child('items')).$asArray();

  $scope.addItem = function(item) { 

    // var iItem = $scope.item.title;

    var userId = $scope.item.title;
      checkIfUserExists(userId);
        };

    function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
      if (exists) {
        alert('user ' + userId + ' exists!');
      } else {
        alert('user ' + userId + ' does not exist!');
      }
    }

    function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
      ref.child('items').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
        userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
      });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime Database is a key/value JSON database. This means that **if you store a title name as a key**, it will be super quick to look it up.

Take the following data for example.

```
{
  "items": {
    "title-1": {
       "something": "foo"
    },
    "title-2": {
       "something": "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

Now let's say we want to check to see if `title-2` exists. We can do this with an easy read.

```
function checkForTitle(title, cb) {
  var itemsRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>/items');
  var titleRef = itemRef.chld(title).once('value', function(snap) {
     cb(snap.exists());
  });
}

checkForTitle('title-2', function(doesExist) {
  console.log(doesExist); // true
});
```

To make sure the check happens on the server, you can write a **Security Rule** for it. Or, better yet use the new **[Bolt Compiler](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html)**.

```
{
  "items": {
     "$item": {
       ".write": "!data.exists()" // don't overwrite existing data
     }
   }
}
```

**You should upgrade your AngularFire version.** I noticed you're using `$firebase().$asArray` which means you're on the `0.9` version of AngularFire, which is unsupported. Look into upgrading to the `1.0+` version which is officially support by Firebase.

Comment: Sorry to be a nube to AngularFire but how would I save my Items with Title name as the key?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. You may not need AngularFire and just use the Firebase SDK with `ref.child('title-2').set({ title: 'title-2' });`. AngularFire is for synchronizing data, saving data doesn't always require downloading it.

Comment: Thanks. At this point I don't think there is any need to synch data.

Comment: Worked like a charm with a bit of tweaking. Thanks.

Is there any way to may it find items even if the case is different? Right now it will not register the same if the case is different.